# lucene convert BytesRef to float

Tags: java, lucene

Given a `BytesRef` encoded with `DelimitedPayloadTokenFilter` and `FloatEncoder()`, how can I extract the actual float value from the `BytesRef`?

```
PayloadAttribute payloadAttribute = stream.getAttribute(PayloadAttribute.class);
BytesRef bytesRef = payloadAttribute.getPayload();
float payloadValue = ...?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, Lucene stores float payload value in 4 bytes `BIG_ENDIAN` order (not sure if this is consistent across all machines). A `ByteBuffer` can be used to extract the value.

```
float payloadValue = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytesRef.bytes).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN).getFloat();
```